# How to re-order pipe-delimited columns in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to reposition every line in a .txt file in the following way below. However I have no idea on how to go about it. Is this possible with Notepad++?

From
apple|apple123@aol.com|orange
celery|celery@aol.com|cabbage
sandwich|sandwich@aol.com|turkey

To
apple|orange|apple123@aol.com
celery|cabbage|celery@aol.com
sandwich|turkey|sandwich@aol.com

Comment: I just found this, which I didn't even know before but looks super useful: [Edit columns in Notepad++ with TextFX plugin](http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2014/10/15/edit-columns-in-notepad-with-textfx-plugin/)

Comment: I would not call this "repositioning lines".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Re-ordering Columns in a Text File

Yes this is possible within vanilla `Notepad++`, though as noted there are also plugins that will do it. A better (more robust) approach might be to use some command-line text-processing tools, but if you need a quick-and-dirty solution you can find that below:

Assuming your exact input (`col1|col2|col3`, pipe delimeter, no pipe in `col2`):

**Find**: `(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*)`

**Replace**: `\1|\3|\2`

works for me here in `Notepad++`, built Jan 2015. Somewhat brutish, but it works.

### Explanation:

`.*` - matches any character (except newline), between zero and unlimited times

`.*?` - matches any character (except newline) as above, in a **non-greedy** manner (ie match *as little as possible*)

`(.*)` - plain brackets denote *capturing group* of above (to use in **Replace** as eg `\1`, `\2`, `\3` etc )

`\|` - `\` escapes pipe (`|`) to match it literally

`\1|\3|\2` - print 1st matching group, pipe, **third** matching group, pipe, second matching group

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad it helped you and hope it will help others :-) It isn't necessary, but you can also click the tick mark to accept an answer if it solves your problem- you are free not to, or to wait for additional better answers too!

Comment: Don't you need to make the `.*` non-greedy, I.e. `.*?` to avoid a lot of backtracking?

Comment: @ExUmbris: usually the optimization starts when the speed seems inadequate

Comment: OTOH deliberately writing a suboptimal query for the sake of not writing a `?` character seems silly.

Comment: Adding a `?` causes the query to fail with the test data, which is why I omitted it.

Comment: `(.*?)|(.*?)|(.*)` works for me.

Comment: @Ryan could swear I tried that and had it not work originally; but it does (of course) so I have updated the answer and explanation to match. Thanks for you input!